# I want to solve the inequality $z′(t)+1≥0$ for all $t≥0$

Tags: functional-inequalities

Let $z(t)$ be a differentiable function for all $t≥0$. I want to solve the inequality:
$$z′(t)+1≥0$$ for all $t≥0$.

where $z′(t)$ is the derivative of $z(t)$.

Comment: Any constant, in fact any linear function with slope $≥-1$ will work. Aren't there any more conditions? The problem seems quite open.

Comment: I cant see an unique solution every $z(t)=t^k$  will give you a solution

Comment: @rewritten: We can add the fact that $z(t)$ is bounded.

Comment: Then $\sin (ax+b)$ will also do for any $b$ and $|a|\leq 1$. And you can easily imagine sums of such functions with varying $|a_n|$ so that $\sum_n |a_n| \leq 1$.

Comment: @arbautjc: I ask if there is a general form of solutions.

Comment: The most general I can see for now is $f(x)=K+\sum_n \lambda_n \sin(a_nx+b_n)$ with $\sum_n |\lambda_n a_n| \leq 1$, with a possibly infinte sum (provided it converges to a differentiable function). If $a_n=n$, $b_n=0$ and suitably decreasing $\lambda_n$, you get Fourier series (you can add a $\cos (nx)$ part of course), so maybe there is something to look at here.

Comment: @arbautjc: What if $z(t)$ is a component of a 3D chaotic system of the form $$x′=y$$ $$y′=-x-yz$$ $$z′=y²-1$$

Comment: Not easy to generalize. You may find classes of solutions, but I'm not sure you can find a characterization of all solutions that will differ from the mere definition in the question. Just a silly opinion, I'm not an expert ;-) Also, are you sure the solution of your system is bounded?

Comment: Yes, at least numerically. And there is a conjecture claiming this result.